# Problems to send mail in production - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I've had problems to send emails in my production environment.

This is my configurations settings:

```
define('EMAIL', serialize(array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mydomain.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'myacount',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'smtp_timeout' => 60,
    'newline' => "\r\n"
```

)));

And that is the debug error:

> 11/06/2018 09:36:03 falhou o emails 220-test.test.com ESMTP Exim 4.91
>
> ## 1 Mon, 11 Jun 2018 09:35:53 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.  hello:
>
> 250-test.test.com Hello test.adm.br [146.66.74.74] 250-SIZE 52428800
>   250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-SMTPUTF8 250 HELP
>   Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Incorrect authentication
>   data  Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method. User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>   Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2018 09:35:50 -0300 From: "CIT" <**myacount**>
>   Return-Path:  To: email1@gmail.com, email2@test.com.br
>   Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Chegou=20um=20termo=20de=20a?==?UTF-8?Q?ceite=20d?=
>   =?UTF-8?Q?o=20cliente=20Teste=20envio?==?UTF-8?Q?=20de=20emai?= =?UTF-8?Q?l!?= Reply-To:  X-Sender: myacountr X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID:
>   <5b1e6ca6dbbb5@test.com.br> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5b1e6ca6dbc02"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_5b1e6ca6dbc02 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Email text!
>
> --B_ALT_5b1e6ca6dbc02 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Email text!
>
> --B_ALT_5b1e6ca6dbc02--

I saw many others similars issues, but no solution was found.

P.s. When i test in my local environment it works fine.

Comment: first Check your server email settings. try to send a sample email using plain php code. if it is working fine. try with CI code.

Comment: looks like the mailserver thinks you're sending spam, and/or doesn't recognise the credentials you provided. So make sure your credentials are correct and that the mailserver allows connections from the server where your code is running. If you're not the admin of the mailserver, you'll have to talk to whoever maintains it and ensure everything is configured correctly. It's not really something we can help with much on a public forum

Comment: I've found the problem. The server hulk protection was blocking the emails send. But a interesting fact was, the reports was not showned on the block logs.